# Event propogation not working in angular4

Tags: angular, event-propagation

I have a div structure like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="showDragDrop == true ? 'show' : 'fade' " 
                      (click)="hideWindow($event); $event.stopPropagation()">
     <input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" .../>
</div>
```

Basically on the hideWindow() method i set showDragDrop =false and this makes my div to get hide.

My issue is, I have a input='file' button inside this div and when I click on this it fires the hideWindow() method.

I tried this

```
 hideWindow(event) {    
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.showDragDrop=false;
  }
```

this

```
(event)="doSomething($event); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

and this

```
(event)="doSomething($event); false"
```

but it is not working

Comment: @yurzui, I was busy making the demo and didn't see your comment :(

Comment: @Vega That's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `event.stopPropagation();` to input's click()

```
<input type="file" (click)="removetheClick($event)" ...>
```

and

```
removetheClick(event){
   event.stopPropagation();   
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rebm2e?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

or, a more concise version, as @yurzui suggested:

```
<input type="file" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" ...>
```